# Android - NullPointerException Error

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, websocket, autobahn

I am working on websocket communication.
From android device(client) to linux-based PC(server).
I succeeded to connect websocket to server. But the problem is I got fail with sending a data(string value)

There is a carousel view with four products. So, when I click photo of product0, I set string as "product0" and send this string value to server. 
I am using Autobahn library.

The code is here

```
import de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection;

public class Myoffers_Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Philips";
    private final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

    public static Fragment newInstance(Myoffers context, int pos, float scale)
    {
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt("pos", pos);
        b.putFloat("scale", scale);
        return Fragment.instantiate(context, Myoffers_Fragment.class.getName(), b);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            return null;
        }

        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mf, container, false);

        int pos = this.getArguments().getInt("pos");
        TextView tv = (TextView) l.findViewById(R.id.text);
        tv.setText("Product " + pos);



        ImageButton product_photo = (ImageButton) l.findViewById(R.id.myoffer_image);


        if (pos == 0) {
            product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
            product_photo.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    String id1 = "Product0";
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current product is : " + id1);
                    mConnection.sendTextMessage(id1);
                    Log.d(TAG, id1 + "is sent to server!");
                }
            });
        }
```

Is it possible that "extends Fragment" makes the error?..
Error is occurred like below..

```
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at de.tavendo.autobahn.WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage(WebSocketConnection.java:137)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at com.example.philips.Myoffers_Fragment$1.onClick(Myoffers_Fragment.java:56)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4446)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 12:02:01.310: E/AndroidRuntime(2712):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error occurred when I click the photo to send string value.

Comment: Where do you actually connect using `mConnection`?

Comment: Last line of `newInstance()` should be replaced with: `Myoffers_Fragment result = new Myoffers_Fragment(); result.setArguments(b); return result;` ... as you seem to return a fragment with empty arguments list. Also, the error is thrown in `WebSocketConnection.sendTextMessage()`. Can you post that code?

Comment: @gunar Which code do you want me to post?..Myoffers_Fragment is the code aboove

Comment: Where can one find the class `WebSocketConnection`? I can't find it in Android packages. Did you use a library or is it something you wrote?

Comment: @gunar WebSocketConnection is included in Autobahn library

Comment: @gunar check this out. 'http://autobahn.ws/static/reference/android/_web_socket_connection_8java_source.html'

Comment: Then Ken's answer seems the valid one.

Comment: @gunar no, the answer is not valid yet! I called'connect()' in the main page

Comment: What do you mean with **called connect in the main page**? Do you have multiple instances of `WebSocketConnection`?

Comment: @gunar Ken said that I need to call "connect()" before using "mConnection". But, in other class, calls "connect()". You can check this detail question here "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17190843/android-autobahn-websocket-sending-message-errornullpointerexception"

Comment: Of course: those are 2 distinct instances (you have a WebSocketConnection instance in main page and a different instance in Fragment) ... no wonder you're getting those NPEs

Comment: Then...how can I fix it..? There is on/off button to connect/disconnect server and I need to send a message on another class.

Comment: The simplest solution: set the connector as singleton. The activity would call: `Connector.getInstance().connect()`. From fragment: `Connector.getInstance().sendMessage(...)`

Comment: Just don't forget to close that connector with `Connector.getInstance.finish()`. Maybe best suited in `Activity.finish()`;

Comment: In the main.class I changed "A.connect("ws://xxx");" to "A.getInstance().connect("ws://192.168.3.100:7681");" But it makes error on getInstance()

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening in your `onClick` here:

```
mConnection.sendTextMessage(id1);
```

Looks like you have declared `mConnection` at the top, but not made any connection.

Looking at the [docs](http://autobahn.ws/android/getstarted#yourfirstclient), you need to call `.connect()` on your `mConnection` before using it.

Line 137 of `WebSocketConnection.java` is:

```
public void sendTextMessage(String payload) {
    mWriter.forward(new WebSocketMessage.TextMessage(payload));
}
```

`mWriter` is null until you call `.connect()`. [Source code](http://autobahn.ws/static/reference/android/_web_socket_connection_8java_source.html)

So, make sure you have a valid connection (by calling `.connect()`) before you use the `mConnection` object.

Comment: Then, where should I call .connect() on my code. Because in the Myoffers_Fragment.class will be produced 4 of it when I access carousel view.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what your architecture is and what you're trying to do, it's hard to say. Personally if I had a need to access this connection a lot I would let my Activity control it, not various Fragments.

Comment: And actually, I made Websocket_connector.class and in that code, I declared 'public void connect(final String wsuri)'

Comment: Well, hopefully I have answered your question. If you have another question about architecture maybe it's better to open another question, or maybe someone else will help. Good luck!

Comment: in the main page, I called 'A.connect("ws://192.168.3.100:7681");' like this. And after that, I accessed MyOffers_Frgment.. but same result. do I need to call connect() in the same class?