# Android - Autobahn Websocket sending message error(NullPointerException)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, websocket, autobahn

I am working on websocket communication with Autobahn. 
On the main.class of my app, I set to call 'connect()' when users click a button.

```
// Toggle Button event
    tButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);    
    tButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked){

            }else{

            }

        }
    });
```

And after that, there is MyOffers.class, and if this class is accessed, 
MyOffers_Fragment class is produced four times automatically, because MyOffers.class contains 'carousel view' and there are four products.

On 'MyOffers_Fragment' class, when users click one of the image of products, message should be sent.

```
if (pos == 0) {
    product_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.myoffers_0);
    product_photo.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            String id = "Product0";
            Log.d(TAG, "Current product is : " + id);
            A.sendMessage(id);  
        }
    });
}
```

But 'mConnection.sendTextMessage(id1);' this line makes 'NullPointerException' error.
There is a class 'Websocket_Connector.class'

```
public class WebSocket_Connector {

    private static final String TAG = "ECHOCLIENT";
    public final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();

    public void connect(final String wsuri) {

          Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to: " + wsuri); 

          try {
             mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onOpen() {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri ); 
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection successful!\n");
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed.");
                }
             });
          } catch (WebSocketException e) {

             Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
          }

     public void sendMessage(String message) {
        connect("ws://192.168.x.xxx:xxxx");
        mConnection.sendTextMessage(message); 
     }

 }
```

I called 'connect()' in the main page class, and after that try to send message.
But, it's not working..Can you please help me out?

Comment: where do you get the NPE?

Comment: @blackbelt mConnection.sendTextMessage(id1); this line

Comment: WebSocketConnection is a class of your own?

Comment: no, it's in a Autobahn library. "http://autobahn.ws/static/reference/android/_web_socket_connection_8java_source.html"

Comment: @blackbelt surely, I added this library on my project.

Comment: I was looking to the code . To me seems that you have to call mConnection.createWriter() before calling mConnection.sendTextMessage

Comment: That's why I called "connect()" on main.class to call writer.

Comment: I see, but you are declaring two different WebSocketConnection

Comment: But..on my app, there is a on/off button to connect/disconnect to server. And I need to send message on another class(MyOffers_Fragment)..then..is there any solution ?..

Comment: Do you want to send a message through WebSocket_Connector ?

Comment: yes, but is there any other method to send a msg?

Comment: try this way: inside WebSocket_Connector create a method named public void sendMessage(String message) { mConnection.sendTextMessage(message); } and call it as A.sendMessage(id1);

Comment: Then, do I need to send message from "MyOffers_Fragment" with 'intent'?

Comment: It is a design problem that you have to deal with.

Comment: Then, what's the best or good way to modify the design?

Comment: that's a good question and still it is up to you. Of course it also depends on the project's constraints. Try wrapping inside WebSocket_Connector the features you need, and access it through an instance of WebSocket_Connector, as I explained in my previous comment.

Comment: what about my question above about 'intent' then?

Comment: Why do you need an INtent?

Comment: As you mentioned, to send a message to sendMessage() method to send it to server. No?

Comment: You misunderstood me. You call the method sendMessage of the type WebSocket_Connector, which wrap a WebSocketConnection and invoke sendTextMessage on an instance of WebSocketConnection

Comment: i cant get it clearly..;-(

Comment: I modified what you suggets.. 'A.sendMessage(id1);' in Fragment class and added sendMessage method in Websocket_connector class..but same problem NPE..

Comment: update the code in the question. Did you remove      mConnection.sendTextMessage(id1); ?

Comment: I edited the question. I modified that when the images clicked in fragment class, send id value to sendMessage method in WebSocket_Connector class. And in that method, try to connect server. but failed. what's the problem..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class WebSocket_Connector {

private static final String TAG = "ECHOCLIENT";
public final WebSocketConnection mConnection = new WebSocketConnection();
private String tmpString = "";
public void connect(final String wsuri) {

      Log.d(TAG, "Connecting to: " + wsuri); 

      try {
         mConnection.connect(wsuri, new WebSocketHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onOpen() {
               Log.d(TAG, "Status: Connected to " + wsuri ); 
               Log.d(TAG, "Connection successful!\n");
               mConnection.sendTextMessage(tmpString); 
               tmpString = "";
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(String payload) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Got echo: " + payload);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int code, String reason) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Connection closed.");
            }
         });
      } catch (WebSocketException e) {

         Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
      }

 public void sendMessage(String message) {

    if (mConnection.isConnected()) 
            mConnection.sendTextMessage(message); 
    else {
       tmpString = message;
       connect("ws://192.168.x.xxx:xxxx");
    }

 }

 }
```

Comment: modified it and "partially" working. Problem is that it connects to server everytime I clicked the image.

Comment: Is there any method that once I connect the server, then just sending a message after that?

Comment: why do you belive that  it connects everytime to the server?

Comment: On the server, I set the log that when client connect to server, it shows the client. When I click the image, server log says every message is sent with different client.

Comment: looking at the library code I found this comment       // don't connect if already connected .. user needs to disconnect first

Comment: you mean, it cannot be connected again if it's connected ?

Comment: so seems. Or at least it is what's author of this library says

Comment: Um...ok..btw, is there any method to use button which is included in main.class which is in another class? and..then what method can disconnect it..?

Comment: I edited the question about the button code in main.class ..do you understand my question.. ;-(

Comment: And in your code, it just goes to else loop. it never goes to if loop..do you know why...?

Comment: I can not right now. Can We continue this conversation tomorrow?